# withSizeLimit Akka directive not working for nested Future method calls

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to upload a file to `S3` & then to `Google Cloud`. However I also want to check the file size before upload. It should be <=3Mb.
I have created a `Route` and it has a `withSizeLimit` `Directive`.

```
fileUploadRoute { (request) =>
    authorizeUser { _ =>                        
        withSizeLimit(3000000) {
          extractDataBytes { dataBytes =>
            complete(uploadFileToCloud(dataBytes))
          }
        }
      }
    
  
private def uploadFileToCloud(
    content: Source[ByteString, Any]
): Future[FileUploadResult] = {
//Upload file to S3
uploadFileto S3(dataBytes)
.flatMap { awsResponse =>
//Upload file to GCP
    uploadFileToGCP(dataBytes)
    .flatMap { gcpResponse =>
    //do something
}
}
.recoverWith {
case (ex: Exception) =>
    //do something
}
}
```

If file size is greater than 3Mb, recoverWith block executes but the standard client error from the `route` is not being thrown. **Am I using the correct `directive`?**

Assume I can consume the incoming `stream` twice.

Comment: I guess that `recoverWith` prevents the route to report back the HTTP error code to the client. You may break this in two steps, first use  `storeUploadedFile` directive to store in tmp location and then in the second step upload to the cloud targets.